# what is use of .mobileconfig files?

Tags: iphone, ios

I recently visit m.freemyapps.com in iphone. This web site ask me to install .mobileconfig file . I do some R&D but didn't got the much intresting. Can any one tell me what is use of mobileconfig ?? why it is use in m.freemyapps.com like this sites ??

Answer (score 21):

> This file will contain all the configurations you want for your users
> iPhones.The mobileconfig file extension is associated with Apple iPhone or iPod Touch. The mobileconfig files are used to customize various configurations and to switch them, whenever the user needs to or to provide access to certain services.
>
> Configuration of mobile Apple devices such as the iPad and iPhone can
> be done using pre-cooked configuration files. These files are
> generated by the iPhone Configuration Utility (iPCU), which spits out
> an XML file with the extension .mobileconfig. Such a file can then be
> put up a web site so that users can download it to apply a certain
> so-called profile, which will be listed in the Settings/General panel
> on the device.

these MobileConfiguration files can contain device security policies and restrictions, VPN configuration information, Wi-Fi settings, email and calendar accounts, and authentication credentials that permit iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad to work with certain enterprise systems. The mobileconfig files can also be encrypted.

The Configuration Utility saves the mobileconfig files, which is may be sent to an email account attached to the users iPhone or iPod Touch. After that, the user can open the attachment in mail and is prompted to install it.

MobileConfig file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple/DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>PayloadContent</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>LDAP Settings</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.ldap.account</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>6df7a612-ce0a-4b4b-bce2-7b844e3c9df0</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.example.iPhone.settings.ldap</string>
            <key>LDAPAccountDescription</key>
            <string>Company Contacts</string>
            <key>LDAPAccountHostName</key>
            <string>ldap.example.com</string>
            <key>LDAPAccountUseSSL</key>
            <false />
            <key>LDAPAccountUserName</key>
            <string>uid=username,dc=example,dc=com</string>
            <key>LDAPSearchSettings</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>LDAPSearchSettingDescription</key>
                    <string>Company Contacts</string>
                    <key>LDAPSearchSettingSearchBase</key>
                    <string></string>
                    <key>LDAPSearchSettingScope</key>
                    <string>LDAPSearchSettingScopeSubtree</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>LDAPSearchSettingDescription</key>
                    <string>Sales Departments</string>
                    <key>LDAPSearchSettingSearchBase</key>
                    <string>ou=Sales,dc=example,dc=com</string>
                    <key>LDAPSearchSettingScope</key>
                    <string>LDAPSearchSettingScopeSubtree</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
            <string>Email Settings</string>
            <key>PayloadType</key>
            <string>com.apple.mail.managed</string>
            <key>PayloadVersion</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>PayloadUUID</key>
            <string>362e5c11-a332-4dfb-b18b-f6f0aac032fd</string>
            <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.example.iPhone.settings.email</string>
            <key>EmailAccountDescription</key>
            <string>Company E-mail</string>
            <key>EmailAccountName</key>
            <string>Full Name</string>
            <key>EmailAccountType</key>
            <string>EmailTypeIMAP</string>
            <key>EmailAddress</key>
            <string>username@example.com</string>
            <key>IncomingMailServerAuthentication</key>
            <string>EmailAuthPassword</string>
            <key>IncomingMailServerHostName</key>
            <string>imap.example.com</string>
            <key>IncomingMailServerUseSSL</key>
            <true />
            <key>IncomingMailServerUsername</key>
            <string>username@es2eng.com</string>
            <key>OutgoingPasswordSameAsIncomingPassword</key>
            <true />
            <key>OutgoingMailServerAuthentication</key>
            <string>EmailAuthPassword</string>
            <key>OutgoingMailServerHostName</key>
            <string>smtp.example.com</string>
            <key>OutgoingMailServerUseSSL</key>
            <true />
            <key>OutgoingMailServerUsername</key>
            <string>username@example.com</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>PayloadOrganization</key>
    <string>Your Organization's Name</string>
    <key>PayloadDisplayName</key>
    <string>Organization iPhone Settings</string>
    <key>PayloadVersion</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>PayloadUUID</key>
    <string>954e6e8b-5489-484c-9b1d-0c9b7bf18e32</string>
    <key>PayloadIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.example.iPhone.settings</string>
    <key>PayloadDescription</key>
    <string>Sets up Organization's LDAP directories and email on the iPhone</string>
    <key>PayloadType</key>
    <string>Configuration</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Sometimes this is the only way to configure certain features, because the device's interface won't let you. A good example is Eduroam wireless networking with TTLS.